# How to compare boolean vectors in R

Tags: r, vector, comparison, boolean, boolean-operations

I have a vector `v` and I want to find all those elements, that have values between 4 and 7.
    v = c(1:9)

```
# indices of elements with values larger than 4
which(v > 4)
# indices of elements with values smaller than 7
which(v < 7)
```

`v>4` and `v<7` give boolean vectors, which I'd like to combine. I tried the following, which did not work for me,...

```
# combination?
matching = which(v>4 && v<7)  # does not work
```

How can I applay a boolean operation on two boolean vectors, that gives me a resulting vector?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use `&` and not `&&`. R is different from other languages in that the `&` is not a bitwise `and`, but a logical operator.

`&&` only evaluates the first element of each vector:

> ‘&’ and ‘&&’ indicate logical AND and ‘|’ and ‘||’ indicate
>        logical OR.  The shorter form performs elementwise comparisons in
>        much the same way as arithmetic operators.  The longer form
>        evaluates left to right examining only the first element of each
>        vector.  Evaluation proceeds only until the result is determined.
>        The longer form is appropriate for programming control-flow and
>        typically preferred in ‘if’ clauses.

See `?"&&"` for more details.

Comment: Nice answer, +1. You may want to indicate where the quoted text comes from: from the help page on `&`, which one can access using `?"&"`. I look at that one at least once every week, since I can never get them straight...